# checker console game in c crash

Tags: c

The program starting up fine but when I type in coordinates it will crash and a popup with:

> Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'x' was corrupted.

I dont understand why it crash when im right now follow a tutorial.

I'm totaly stuck.... Any suggest or hints?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


void print_board(int board[9][8])
{
    int x,y;
    char z = 1;
    system("cls");
    for(x=1;x<9;x++){
        printf("%d",z);
        z++;
        for(y=1;y<9;y++){
            printf("|");
            switch(board[x][y]){
            case 0:
                printf(" ");
                break;
            case 1:
                printf("x");
                break;
            case 2:
                printf("o");
                break;
            case 3:
                printf("X");
                break;
            case 4:
                printf("O");
                break;
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9\n");
}


void set_defaults(int board[9][8])
{
    board[1][2]= 1; board[1][4]= 1; board[1][6]= 1; board[1][8]= 1;
    board[2][1]= 1; board[2][3]= 1; board[2][5]= 1; board[2][7]= 1;
    board[3][2]= 1; board[3][4]= 1; board[3][6]= 1; board[3][8]= 1;
    board[6][1]= 2; board[6][3]= 2; board[6][5]= 2; board[6][7]= 2;
    board[7][2]= 2; board[7][4]= 2; board[7][6]= 2; board[7][8]= 2;
    board[8][1]= 2; board[8][3]= 2; board[8][5]= 2; board[8][7]= 2;
}

int Enemy(int you)
{
    if(you == 1 || you == 3){
        return 2;
    }
    if(you == 2 || you == 4){
        return 1;
    }
}

void Check_if_bacame_queen(int x, int y, int board[9][8], int turn)
{
    if(turn == 1){
        if(x == 3){
            board[x][y] = 3;
        }
    }
    if(turn == 2){
        if(x == 1){
            board[x][y] = 4;
        }
    }
}

int NextChainValid(int board[9][8], int x[4])
{
    if(board[x[3]+1][x[4]+1]==Enemy(board[x[3]][x[4]])  ||  board[x[3]+1][x[4]+1]==Enemy(board[x[3]][x[4]]+2) ){
        return 1;
    }
    else if(board[x[3]+1][x[4]-1]==Enemy(board[x[3]][x[4]])  || board[x[3]+1][x[4]-1] == Enemy(board[x[3]][x[4]]+2)){
        return 1;
    }
    else if(board[x[3]-1][x[4]+1] == Enemy(board[x[3]][x[4]])  ||  board[x[3]-1][x[4]+1] == Enemy(board[x[3]][x[4]]+2 )){
        return 1;
    }
    else if(board[x[3]-1][x[4]-1] == Enemy(board[x[3]][x[4]]) || board[x[3]-1][x[4]-1] == Enemy(board[x[3]][x[4]] +2) ){
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }
}

void get_co(int board[9][8],int turn, int peshka[2])
{
    int x[4];
    if(turn == 1){
        printf("X's turn\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("O's turn\n");
    }
    printf("Write XYAZ: \n");
    scanf("%d %d %d %d",&x[1],&x[2],&x[3],&x[4]);
    if(board[x[1]][x[2]]==turn || board[x[1]][x[2]] == turn+2){//check if move is valid

        if(turn == 1){
            if(x[3] == x[1]+1 && x[4]==x[2]+1 || x[4] == x[2]-1){//checking if the new co of the peshka are valid
                board[x[1]][x[2]] = 0; //making them
                board[x[3]][x[4]] = turn;
                Check_if_bacame_queen(x[3],x[4],board,turn);
            }
            else if(x[3] == x[1]+2 && x[4] == x[2]+2 || x[4] == x[2]-2){
                int x2,y2;
                board[x[1]][x[2]] = 0;
                board[x[3]][x[4]] = turn;
                if(x[1]>x[3]){
                    x2=x[1]-1;
                }
                else{
                    x2 = x[3]-1;
                }
                if(x[2]>x[4]){
                    y2=x[2]-1;
                }
                else{
                    y2 = x[3]-1;
                }
                board[x2][y2]=0;
                peshka[turn+1]--;//lovering peshkas that enemy has
                Check_if_bacame_queen(x[3],x[4],board,turn);
                if(NextChainValid(board,x)){
                    get_co(board,turn,peshka);//recursion
                }
            }
            else{
                printf("Invalid move!\n");

            }
        }//turn 1
        else if(turn == 2){
            if(x[3]==x[1]-1 && x[4]==x[2]+1 || x[4]==x[2]-1){//checking if the new co of peshka are valid
                board[x[1]][x[2]]=0;
                board[x[3]][x[4]]=turn;
                Check_if_bacame_queen(x[3],x[4],board,turn);
            }
            else if(x[3]==x[1]-2 && x[4]==x[2]+2 || x[4]==x[2]-2){//checking if the new co is 
                int x2,y2;
                board[x[1]][x[2]]=0;
                board[x[3]][x[4]]=turn;

                if(x[1]>x[3]){
                    x2 = x[1]-1;
                }
                else{
                    x2 = x[3]-1;
                }
                if(x[2]>x[4]){
                    y2 = x[2]-1;
                }
                else{
                    y2 = x[4]-1;
                }
                board[x2][y2] = 0;
                peshka[turn-1]--;//lovering enemys peshkas
                Check_if_bacame_queen(x[3],x[4],board,turn);
                if(NextChainValid(board,x)){
                    get_co(board,turn,peshka);//recursion
                }
            }
            else{
                printf("Invalide move!");

            }
        }
        else if(turn == 3){//QUEEN
            if(x[3] == x[1]-1 || x[3]==x[1]+1 && x[4]==x[2]+1  || x[4]==x[2]+1){
                board[x[1]][x[2]] = 0;
                board[x[3]][x[4]] = turn;
                Check_if_bacame_queen(x[3],x[4],board,turn);
            }
            else if(x[3]==x[1]+2 || x[3]==x[1]-2 && x[4]==x[2]+2 || x[4]==x[2]-2){
                int x2,y2;
                board[x[1]][x[2]] = 0;
                board[x[3]][x[4]] = turn;

                if(x[1]>x[3]){
                    x2 = x[1]-1;
                }
                else{
                    x2=x[3]-1;
                }
                if(x[2]>x[4]){
                    y2 = x[2]-1;
                }
                else{
                    y2 = x[4]-1;
                }
                board[x2][y2]=0;
                peshka[turn-1]--;
                Check_if_bacame_queen(x[3],x[4],board,turn);
                if(NextChainValid(board,x)){
                    get_co(board,turn,peshka);//recursion
                }
            }
            else{
                printf("Invalide move!");

            }
        }
        else if(turn == 4){
            if(x[3]==x[1]-1 && x[4]==x[2]+1 || x[4]==x[2]-1){
                board[x[1]][x[2]] = 0;
                board[x[3]][x[4]] = turn;
                Check_if_bacame_queen(x[3],x[4],board,turn);
            }
            else if(x[3]==x[1]+2 && x[4]==x[2]+2 || x[4]==x[2]-2){
                int x2,y2;
                board[x[1]][x[2]] = 0;
                board[x[3]][x[4]] = turn;

                if(x[1]>x[3]){
                    x2 = x[1]-1;
                }
                else{
                    x2 = x[3]-1;
                }
                if(x[2]>x[4]){
                    y2 = x[2]-1;
                }
                else{
                    y2 = x[4]-1;
                }
                board[x2][y2]=0;
                peshka[turn-3]--;
                Check_if_bacame_queen(x[3],x[4],board,turn);
                if(NextChainValid(board,x)){
                    get_co(board,turn,peshka);//recursion
                }
            }
            else{
                printf("Invalide move!");

            }
        }
    }
}

int Winner(int x, int o){
    if(x == 0){
        printf("X won!");
        return 1;
    }
    else if(o == 0){
        printf("O won!");
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int board[9][8]={0}, turn=2, peshka[2] = {12};
    set_defaults(board);

    while(Winner(peshka[1],peshka[2])){
        print_board(board);
        get_co(board,turn,peshka);
        if(turn == 2){
            turn = 1;
        }
        else{
            turn = 2;
        }
    }
    scanf("!");
}
```

Comment: Suggestion - Learn you use your environment's debugger. Then step through your code.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is not a site for "Here are a couple of hundred lines of code. What's the problem with it?" kinds of questions. You'll need to use the debugger (or at the very least a series of `printf()` statements) to narrow down the area of the problem, and then you can post the **relevant portion** of the code and a description of the problem you're having with that code, and ask a specific question. [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) can help you figure out how to post the problem area of the code. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Running `clang` to compile your code shows that there are numerous locations where you index off the end of an array (usually the board, but sometimes other arrays as well). Remember that C arrays are indexed from 0, not 1!

A full dump of the compiler diagnostics follows:

```
checkers.c:41:53: warning: array index 8 is past the end of the array (which contains 8 elements) [-Warray-bounds]
    board[1][2]= 1; board[1][4]= 1; board[1][6]= 1; board[1][8]= 1;
                                                    ^        ~
checkers.c:39:19: note: array 'board' declared here
void set_defaults(int board[9][8])
                  ^
checkers.c:43:53: warning: array index 8 is past the end of the array (which contains 8 elements) [-Warray-bounds]
    board[3][2]= 1; board[3][4]= 1; board[3][6]= 1; board[3][8]= 1;
                                                    ^        ~
checkers.c:39:19: note: array 'board' declared here
void set_defaults(int board[9][8])
                  ^
checkers.c:45:53: warning: array index 8 is past the end of the array (which contains 8 elements) [-Warray-bounds]
    board[7][2]= 2; board[7][4]= 2; board[7][6]= 2; board[7][8]= 2;
                                                    ^        ~
checkers.c:39:19: note: array 'board' declared here
void set_defaults(int board[9][8])
                  ^
checkers.c:57:1: warning: control may reach end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
}
^
checkers.c:106:31: warning: '&&' within '||' [-Wlogical-op-parentheses]
            if(x[3] == x[1]+1 && x[4]==x[2]+1 || x[4] == x[2]-1){//checking if the new co of the peshka are valid
               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ~~
checkers.c:106:31: note: place parentheses around the '&&' expression to silence this warning
            if(x[3] == x[1]+1 && x[4]==x[2]+1 || x[4] == x[2]-1){//checking if the new co of the peshka are valid
                              ^
               (                             )
checkers.c:111:36: warning: '&&' within '||' [-Wlogical-op-parentheses]
            else if(x[3] == x[1]+2 && x[4] == x[2]+2 || x[4] == x[2]-2){
                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ~~
checkers.c:111:36: note: place parentheses around the '&&' expression to silence this warning
            else if(x[3] == x[1]+2 && x[4] == x[2]+2 || x[4] == x[2]-2){
                                   ^
                    (                               )
checkers.c:140:29: warning: '&&' within '||' [-Wlogical-op-parentheses]
            if(x[3]==x[1]-1 && x[4]==x[2]+1 || x[4]==x[2]-1){//checking if the new co of peshka are valid
               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ~~
checkers.c:140:29: note: place parentheses around the '&&' expression to silence this warning
            if(x[3]==x[1]-1 && x[4]==x[2]+1 || x[4]==x[2]-1){//checking if the new co of peshka are valid
                            ^
               (                           )
checkers.c:145:34: warning: '&&' within '||' [-Wlogical-op-parentheses]
            else if(x[3]==x[1]-2 && x[4]==x[2]+2 || x[4]==x[2]-2){//checking if the new co is 
                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ~~
checkers.c:145:34: note: place parentheses around the '&&' expression to silence this warning
            else if(x[3]==x[1]-2 && x[4]==x[2]+2 || x[4]==x[2]-2){//checking if the new co is 
                                 ^
                    (                           )
checkers.c:175:47: warning: '&&' within '||' [-Wlogical-op-parentheses]
            if(x[3] == x[1]-1 || x[3]==x[1]+1 && x[4]==x[2]+1  || x[4]==x[2]+1){
                              ~~ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
checkers.c:175:47: note: place parentheses around the '&&' expression to silence this warning
            if(x[3] == x[1]-1 || x[3]==x[1]+1 && x[4]==x[2]+1  || x[4]==x[2]+1){
                                              ^
                                 (                           )
checkers.c:180:50: warning: '&&' within '||' [-Wlogical-op-parentheses]
            else if(x[3]==x[1]+2 || x[3]==x[1]-2 && x[4]==x[2]+2 || x[4]==x[2]-2){
                                 ~~ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
checkers.c:180:50: note: place parentheses around the '&&' expression to silence this warning
            else if(x[3]==x[1]+2 || x[3]==x[1]-2 && x[4]==x[2]+2 || x[4]==x[2]-2){
                                                 ^
                                    (                           )
checkers.c:210:29: warning: '&&' within '||' [-Wlogical-op-parentheses]
            if(x[3]==x[1]-1 && x[4]==x[2]+1 || x[4]==x[2]-1){
               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ~~
checkers.c:210:29: note: place parentheses around the '&&' expression to silence this warning
            if(x[3]==x[1]-1 && x[4]==x[2]+1 || x[4]==x[2]-1){
                            ^
               (                           )
checkers.c:215:34: warning: '&&' within '||' [-Wlogical-op-parentheses]
            else if(x[3]==x[1]+2 && x[4]==x[2]+2 || x[4]==x[2]-2){
                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ~~
checkers.c:215:34: note: place parentheses around the '&&' expression to silence this warning
            else if(x[3]==x[1]+2 && x[4]==x[2]+2 || x[4]==x[2]-2){
                                 ^
                    (                           )
checkers.c:106:34: warning: array index 4 is past the end of the array (which contains 4 elements) [-Warray-bounds]
            if(x[3] == x[1]+1 && x[4]==x[2]+1 || x[4] == x[2]-1){//checking if the new co of the peshka are valid
                                 ^ ~
checkers.c:94:5: note: array 'x' declared here
    int x[4];
    ^
checkers.c:106:50: warning: array index 4 is past the end of the array (which contains 4 elements) [-Warray-bounds]
            if(x[3] == x[1]+1 && x[4]==x[2]+1 || x[4] == x[2]-1){//checking if the new co of the peshka are valid
                                                 ^ ~
checkers.c:94:5: note: array 'x' declared here
    int x[4];
    ^
checkers.c:109:44: warning: array index 4 is past the end of the array (which contains 4 elements) [-Warray-bounds]
                Check_if_bacame_queen(x[3],x[4],board,turn);
                                           ^ ~
checkers.c:94:5: note: array 'x' declared here
    int x[4];
    ^
checkers.c:111:39: warning: array index 4 is past the end of the array (which contains 4 elements) [-Warray-bounds]
            else if(x[3] == x[1]+2 && x[4] == x[2]+2 || x[4] == x[2]-2){
                                      ^ ~
checkers.c:94:5: note: array 'x' declared here
    int x[4];
    ^
checkers.c:111:57: warning: array index 4 is past the end of the array (which contains 4 elements) [-Warray-bounds]
            else if(x[3] == x[1]+2 && x[4] == x[2]+2 || x[4] == x[2]-2){
                                                        ^ ~
checkers.c:94:5: note: array 'x' declared here
    int x[4];
    ^
checkers.c:121:25: warning: array index 4 is past the end of the array (which contains 4 elements) [-Warray-bounds]
                if(x[2]>x[4]){
                        ^ ~
checkers.c:94:5: note: array 'x' declared here
    int x[4];
    ^
checkers.c:129:44: warning: array index 4 is past the end of the array (which contains 4 elements) [-Warray-bounds]
                Check_if_bacame_queen(x[3],x[4],board,turn);
                                           ^ ~
checkers.c:94:5: note: array 'x' declared here
    int x[4];
    ^
checkers.c:140:32: warning: array index 4 is past the end of the array (which contains 4 elements) [-Warray-bounds]
            if(x[3]==x[1]-1 && x[4]==x[2]+1 || x[4]==x[2]-1){//checking if the new co of peshka are valid
                               ^ ~
checkers.c:94:5: note: array 'x' declared here
    int x[4];
    ^
checkers.c:140:48: warning: array index 4 is past the end of the array (which contains 4 elements) [-Warray-bounds]
            if(x[3]==x[1]-1 && x[4]==x[2]+1 || x[4]==x[2]-1){//checking if the new co of peshka are valid
                                               ^ ~
checkers.c:94:5: note: array 'x' declared here
    int x[4];
    ^
checkers.c:143:44: warning: array index 4 is past the end of the array (which contains 4 elements) [-Warray-bounds]
                Check_if_bacame_queen(x[3],x[4],board,turn);
                                           ^ ~
checkers.c:94:5: note: array 'x' declared here
    int x[4];
    ^
checkers.c:145:37: warning: array index 4 is past the end of the array (which contains 4 elements) [-Warray-bounds]
            else if(x[3]==x[1]-2 && x[4]==x[2]+2 || x[4]==x[2]-2){//checking if the new co is 
                                    ^ ~
checkers.c:94:5: note: array 'x' declared here
    int x[4];
    ^
checkers.c:145:53: warning: array index 4 is past the end of the array (which contains 4 elements) [-Warray-bounds]
            else if(x[3]==x[1]-2 && x[4]==x[2]+2 || x[4]==x[2]-2){//checking if the new co is 
                                                    ^ ~
checkers.c:94:5: note: array 'x' declared here
    int x[4];
    ^
checkers.c:156:25: warning: array index 4 is past the end of the array (which contains 4 elements) [-Warray-bounds]
                if(x[2]>x[4]){
                        ^ ~
checkers.c:94:5: note: array 'x' declared here
    int x[4];
    ^
checkers.c:160:26: warning: array index 4 is past the end of the array (which contains 4 elements) [-Warray-bounds]
                    y2 = x[4]-1;
                         ^ ~
checkers.c:94:5: note: array 'x' declared here
    int x[4];
    ^
checkers.c:164:44: warning: array index 4 is past the end of the array (which contains 4 elements) [-Warray-bounds]
                Check_if_bacame_queen(x[3],x[4],board,turn);
                                           ^ ~
checkers.c:94:5: note: array 'x' declared here
    int x[4];
    ^
checkers.c:175:50: warning: array index 4 is past the end of the array (which contains 4 elements) [-Warray-bounds]
            if(x[3] == x[1]-1 || x[3]==x[1]+1 && x[4]==x[2]+1  || x[4]==x[2]+1){
                                                 ^ ~
checkers.c:94:5: note: array 'x' declared here
    int x[4];
    ^
checkers.c:175:67: warning: array index 4 is past the end of the array (which contains 4 elements) [-Warray-bounds]
            if(x[3] == x[1]-1 || x[3]==x[1]+1 && x[4]==x[2]+1  || x[4]==x[2]+1){
                                                                  ^ ~
checkers.c:94:5: note: array 'x' declared here
    int x[4];
    ^
checkers.c:178:44: warning: array index 4 is past the end of the array (which contains 4 elements) [-Warray-bounds]
                Check_if_bacame_queen(x[3],x[4],board,turn);
                                           ^ ~
checkers.c:94:5: note: array 'x' declared here
    int x[4];
    ^
checkers.c:180:53: warning: array index 4 is past the end of the array (which contains 4 elements) [-Warray-bounds]
            else if(x[3]==x[1]+2 || x[3]==x[1]-2 && x[4]==x[2]+2 || x[4]==x[2]-2){
                                                    ^ ~
checkers.c:94:5: note: array 'x' declared here
    int x[4];
    ^
checkers.c:180:69: warning: array index 4 is past the end of the array (which contains 4 elements) [-Warray-bounds]
            else if(x[3]==x[1]+2 || x[3]==x[1]-2 && x[4]==x[2]+2 || x[4]==x[2]-2){
                                                                    ^ ~
checkers.c:94:5: note: array 'x' declared here
    int x[4];
    ^
checkers.c:191:25: warning: array index 4 is past the end of the array (which contains 4 elements) [-Warray-bounds]
                if(x[2]>x[4]){
                        ^ ~
checkers.c:94:5: note: array 'x' declared here
    int x[4];
    ^
checkers.c:195:26: warning: array index 4 is past the end of the array (which contains 4 elements) [-Warray-bounds]
                    y2 = x[4]-1;
                         ^ ~
checkers.c:94:5: note: array 'x' declared here
    int x[4];
    ^
checkers.c:199:44: warning: array index 4 is past the end of the array (which contains 4 elements) [-Warray-bounds]
                Check_if_bacame_queen(x[3],x[4],board,turn);
                                           ^ ~
checkers.c:94:5: note: array 'x' declared here
    int x[4];
    ^
checkers.c:210:32: warning: array index 4 is past the end of the array (which contains 4 elements) [-Warray-bounds]
            if(x[3]==x[1]-1 && x[4]==x[2]+1 || x[4]==x[2]-1){
                               ^ ~
checkers.c:94:5: note: array 'x' declared here
    int x[4];
    ^
checkers.c:210:48: warning: array index 4 is past the end of the array (which contains 4 elements) [-Warray-bounds]
            if(x[3]==x[1]-1 && x[4]==x[2]+1 || x[4]==x[2]-1){
                                               ^ ~
checkers.c:94:5: note: array 'x' declared here
    int x[4];
    ^
checkers.c:213:44: warning: array index 4 is past the end of the array (which contains 4 elements) [-Warray-bounds]
                Check_if_bacame_queen(x[3],x[4],board,turn);
                                           ^ ~
checkers.c:94:5: note: array 'x' declared here
    int x[4];
    ^
checkers.c:215:37: warning: array index 4 is past the end of the array (which contains 4 elements) [-Warray-bounds]
            else if(x[3]==x[1]+2 && x[4]==x[2]+2 || x[4]==x[2]-2){
                                    ^ ~
checkers.c:94:5: note: array 'x' declared here
    int x[4];
    ^
checkers.c:215:53: warning: array index 4 is past the end of the array (which contains 4 elements) [-Warray-bounds]
            else if(x[3]==x[1]+2 && x[4]==x[2]+2 || x[4]==x[2]-2){
                                                    ^ ~
checkers.c:94:5: note: array 'x' declared here
    int x[4];
    ^
checkers.c:226:25: warning: array index 4 is past the end of the array (which contains 4 elements) [-Warray-bounds]
                if(x[2]>x[4]){
                        ^ ~
checkers.c:94:5: note: array 'x' declared here
    int x[4];
    ^
checkers.c:230:26: warning: array index 4 is past the end of the array (which contains 4 elements) [-Warray-bounds]
                    y2 = x[4]-1;
                         ^ ~
checkers.c:94:5: note: array 'x' declared here
    int x[4];
    ^
checkers.c:234:44: warning: array index 4 is past the end of the array (which contains 4 elements) [-Warray-bounds]
                Check_if_bacame_queen(x[3],x[4],board,turn);
                                           ^ ~
checkers.c:94:5: note: array 'x' declared here
    int x[4];
    ^
checkers.c:263:22: warning: suggest braces around initialization of subobject [-Wmissing-braces]
    int board[9][8]={0}, turn=2, peshka[2] = {12};
                     ^
                     {}
checkers.c:266:28: warning: array index 2 is past the end of the array (which contains 2 elements) [-Warray-bounds]
    while(Winner(peshka[1],peshka[2])){
                           ^      ~
checkers.c:263:5: note: array 'peshka' declared here
    int board[9][8]={0}, turn=2, peshka[2] = {12};
    ^
45 warnings generated.
```